# What is exactly null in kotlin and why i can't cause NPE with it?

Tags: kotlin

Look at the following code running in Kotlin REPL:

```
>>> null.takeIf({1==2})
res4: kotlin.Nothing? = null
```

Why this don't cause NullPointerException?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html because NullPointerException on the tiniest thing is annoying

Comment: Because `takeIf` is an extension function, not member function.

Answer (score 7):

You code doesn't cause NullPointerException because `takeIf` is an extension function.
Extension functions are translated into method receiver, first argument being the object you invoked your function on.

So instead of `null.takeIf { false }` (simplifying your example), you could wonder why the following function doesn't throw a NullPointerException:

```
fun <T> takeIf(me: T, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    ...
}
```

Well, for that we need to look into `takeIf()` implementation (removing annotations and contract):

```
public inline fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    return if (predicate(this)) this else null
}
```

So, in case your predicate is false (as in your example, `1==2`), it just short-circuits and returns null.

What if it's `true`, then? Will we finally get a NullPointer?

Nope:

```
val nothing: Nothing? = null.takeIf {
    true
}
```

Comment: "Here my guess is that compiler is doing some optimizations, since our null is a constant." Why do you think that's relevant? It's just that `predicate(this)` (in this case `{ true } (null)`) returns `true`, so `this` (`null`) is returned.

Comment: But it doesn't return `null`. It returns `Nothing`, which is a class defined in the standard library.

Comment: 1. No, the value returned is `null`. You can test it: `nothing == null` is true. Or just see it in the question: `= null`.

Comment: 2. The type is `Nothing?`, not `Nothing`, which is why `null` is a legal value at all.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin design approach for types aims to eliminate NPEs on purpose. Conditions that might trigger one are limited to, as seen on the docs:

- An explicit call to throw NullPointerException();
- Usage of the !! operator that is described below;
- Some data inconsistency with regard to initialization, such as when:

  - An uninitialized this available in a constructor is passed and used somewhere ("leaking this");
  - A superclass constructor calls an open member whose implementation in the derived class uses uninitialized state;
- Java interoperation:

  - Attempts to access a member on a null reference of a platform type;
  - Generic types used for Java interoperation with incorrect nullability, e.g. a piece of Java code might add null into a Kotlin MutableList, meaning that MutableList should be used for working with it;
  - Other issues caused by external Java code.

> The third option is for NPE-lovers: the not-null assertion operator
>   (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if
>   the value is null. We can write b!!, and this will return a non-null
>   value of b (e.g., a String in our example) or throw an NPE if b is
>   null:
>
> `val l = b!!.length`
>
> Thus, if you want an NPE, you can have it, but you
>   have to ask for it explicitly, and it does not appear out of the blue.

So your code is behaving as expected. See the link for more info

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the code behaves as expected.

Comment: How??? It clearly outlines the limited set of cases that cause a NPE in Kotlin, which the question does not fit into. Do I need to explain Aristotelian logic too, to make it even clearer how that means this is expected behavior?